# How to Print the string in following manner using PHP for loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I would like to know, how can we print the data using For loop in PHP in this format.

```
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X
```

I am the beginner of PHP, and unable to make the codes for this.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: I am the beginner of PHP, and unable to solve the question.

Comment: This has to be the most common assignment that CS teachers give. There are tons of information online about this (and virtually all other permutations of it). A little Googling would've saved you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using loop

```
$n = 5;
for($i=$n;$i>0;$i--)
  {
   for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
   {
    echo "*";
   }
  echo"<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're asking for here, your question is really unclear, but if you want to print output in this manner, something like this might help, but then again. I have no idea what you want here.

As everyone else is saying, you should google since I suppose this is a homework assignment.

```
$count = 5;
for($i = $count; $i >0 ; $i--)
{
     for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++)
     {
           echo "X";
     }
     echo "</br>"; 

}
```

Comment: He obviously can't be bothered to do his homework himself, so he asked SO to do it for him. I suppose this really doesn't help him in the long run. ;)

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right.

Comment: And someone downvotes it, always fun to try to be helpful... :(

Comment: Lol, yeah, I saw that. Guess people agreed with me about this not being helpful? =/

Comment: [**your code has  too many typo**](http://codepad.org/ZOXqzg3X) please run your code before posting here

Comment: I am learning PHP with own resources. somebody told me about the Stack overflow. I Used it, but if this website is only for professionals, than no worry I can remove my question and for future updates.

Comment: @Sam no not at all ... its for those who have first tried stuff than ask question in other word shows efforts .. there is no problem to be a newbie

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 5;
while($i > 0){
    echo str_pad('', $i, 'X') . '<br>';
    $i--;
}
```